installing klaviyo-api version 8 in node 16.15.1
I am using node 16.15.1  and npm 8.11.0 and I was trying to install klavio-api  since the klavio has notified that they are deprecating their v1/v2 legacies
When attempting to install klaviyo-api@8.0.0 via npm, I encountered a blocking issue:
npm install klaviyo-api@8.0.0

i was blocked by

npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'shaven@0.8.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '~0.12.2' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.1', npm: '8.11.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

so i tried to install the latest version of shaven
npm install shaven so i got the same installation error how can i fix and why dont they give the backward competibilty to theses packages
It's frustrating that the packages don't support newer versions of Node.js. I also checked the documentation for klavio-api, but found no information regarding Node.js compatibility.
